# Select menu opening over DIV below

Tags: html, css, select, menu

I was wondering if its possible to get a select menus options to push down any DIVS below them? I have managed to do it with mobile menus etc but have no success with a simple select menu.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
body{
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div >
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 
<div style="width:100%; height:100px; background-color:#F12B2E;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

In the example below the menu overlaps the red div box below. Can this be done? Will it work flawlessly on all browser types? Am I better off using a jquery UI? Thanks in advance

Comment: Not possible with native select. You need some JS plugin.

Comment: @max thanks I thought so I will just use the size attribute and add a margin to the bottom.